# Calendar REST API for on-premise exchange 2016 (No hybrid)

Tags: exchange-server, office365api, outlook-restapi, exchange-server-2016

I have been using Calendar Rest API for office 365 and from the documentation it seems that there are no plans of introducing these API's for an non-hybrid On-Premise Exchange 2016.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2016/09/26/on-premises-architectural-requirements-for-the-rest-api/

Is this a correct understanding? I can however see an additional virtual directory (API) similar to EWS in an Exchange 2016 R3 deployment. I am also wondering how will client credential OAUTH flow for a daemon app work on Exchange 2016?

We have customers that have an on-premise exchange 2016 and need a clarification.

Comment: Any update on this?